# rsacryptoserviceprovider.VerifyData always returns false

Tags: c#, php, rsa, public-key-encryption, phpseclib

Below is my C# Program that verifies a response from a php script which is using phpseclib

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var payment =
                "VUQxMzE1MTg0OTk0MDM2MzIyMDJ8VDAwMDAxN0kxMFVEMTMxNTE4NDk5NDAzNjMyMjAyfDIwMTctMTAtMDd8MHxwYXltZW50IHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWx8MjAyNTQ=";
            var signature =
                "V0T9ZedZW8oB9uy4PazRIxWHvJ7rR+FVtnGjUy30mSKqgmEceZWE1aBvkQWeG4ERjAXHjsRge0D0MlHd9zvXjrLog+G5nWBHIu52O0srCd9d71JVztMQy8fV5oSnRPtlUpgdmn8QDnJ27XrbaHzNxnFyybTQhmbfxkT0oJ0MEOk=";

            var sigByte = Convert.FromBase64String(signature);
            var payBite = Convert.FromBase64String(payment);

            Verify(payBite, sigByte);
        }

        public static bool Verify(byte[] payment, byte[] signature)
        {
            var key = Resources.PublicKey;
            var cipher = Crypto.DecodeX509PublicKey(key);

            var res = cipher.VerifyData(payment, "SHA256", signature);
            return res;
        }
```

the public key used is below:

```
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDSiXzUuH9ePZgSLYrzZ0qhta25
HCb+WG48wIKUl+cQNC/Fl/KZG2cSwRXdo8KZLVWWO5qwzplfTWEylg4IqRA48rYY
f/b+Y7QhORKeAws4pttLZJBbh1mIbZ9HXfQ+zBjP+zfJZ1YjSFs2uZdwSt1itUcJ
/GQFct8GoUevNELG7wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

but the verify method seems to be returning false all the time. any idea why this happens.

the same content works in the php code which the vendor gave to me

```
<?php
//load RSA library
include 'Crypt/RSA.php';
//initialize RSA
$rsa = new Crypt_RSA();
//decode & get POST parameters
$payment = base64_decode("VUQxMzE1MTg0OTk0MDM2MzIyMDJ8VDAwMDAxN0kxMFVEMTMxNTE4NDk5NDAzNjMyMjAyfDIwMTctMTAtMDd8MHxwYXltZW50IHN1Y2Nlc3NmdWx8MjAyNTQ=");
$signature = base64_decode("V0T9ZedZW8oB9uy4PazRIxWHvJ7rR+FVtnGjUy30mSKqgmEceZWE1aBvkQWeG4ERjAXHjsRge0D0MlHd9zvXjrLog+G5nWBHIu52O0srCd9d71JVztMQy8fV5oSnRPtlUpgdmn8QDnJ27XrbaHzNxnFyybTQhmbfxkT0oJ0MEOk=");

//load public key for signature matching
$publickey = "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDSiXzUuH9ePZgSLYrzZ0qhta25
HCb+WG48wIKUl+cQNC/Fl/KZG2cSwRXdo8KZLVWWO5qwzplfTWEylg4IqRA48rYY
f/b+Y7QhORKeAws4pttLZJBbh1mIbZ9HXfQ+zBjP+zfJZ1YjSFs2uZdwSt1itUcJ
/GQFct8GoUevNELG7wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----";
$rsa->loadKey($publickey);
//verify signature
$signature_status = $rsa->verify($payment, $signature);
//get payment response in segments
//payment format: order_id|order_refference_number|date_time_transaction|payment_gateway_used|status_code|comment;
$responseVariables = explode('|', $payment);       


    //display values
    echo $signature_status;

    echo '<br/>';
    var_dump($responseVariables);


?>
```

Any idea what i'm doing wrong here. i tried passing "SHA512", "MD5" all in the C# code and still returns false.

Comment: According to phpseclib documentation the default hash algorithm is sha1. Have you tried that one in C#?

Comment: @Michael yeap. that too gave the same result

Comment: I wonder if might also you might need to do (in PHP) `$rsa->setEncryptionMode(CRYPT_RSA_ENCRYPTION_PKCS1);`. OAEP encryption is what phpseclib uses by default. It's more secure but less commonly used than PKCS1.

Comment: @neubert php is actually from a vendor. i don't have much control over it

Comment: Are you sure that the vendor uses `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PKCS1` and not `CRYPT_RSA_SIGNATURE_PSS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, seems like the vendor is NOT using PKCS1, he's using PSS. Verify it this way (requires Bouncy Castle!):

```
    public static bool Verify(byte[] payment, byte[] signature)
    {
        var pub = @"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDSiXzUuH9ePZgSLYrzZ0qhta25HCb+WG48wIKUl+cQNC/Fl/KZG2cSwRXdo8KZLVWWO5qwzplfTWEylg4IqRA48rYYf/b+Y7QhORKeAws4pttLZJBbh1mIbZ9HXfQ+zBjP+zfJZ1YjSFs2uZdwSt1itUcJ/GQFct8GoUevNELG7wIDAQAB";

        byte[] raw = Convert.FromBase64String(pub);
        AsymmetricKeyParameter aKey = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(raw);
        RsaKeyParameters rKey = (RsaKeyParameters)aKey;

        PssSigner pss = new PssSigner(new RsaEngine(), new Sha1Digest(), 20);
        pss.Init(false, rKey);
        pss.BlockUpdate(payment, 0, payment.Length);
        var res = pss.VerifySignature(signature);

        return res;
    }
```

Comment: Yes.. i guess their doc and implementation seems to be diff. thanks a lot for the  idea.

Answer (score 3):

PSS is supported in-the-box with .NET 4.6+, but requires using the RSACng class (CAPI, which RSACryptoServiceProvider is based on, doesn't offer it).

```
public static bool Verify(byte[] payment, byte[] signature)
{
    var key = Resources.PublicKey;
    // Change the function this calls to return RSACng instead of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
    RSA cipher = Crypto.DecodeX509PublicKey(key);

    // or, failing being able to change it:
    RSA tmp = new RSACng();
    tmp.ImportParameters(cipher.ExportParameters(false));
    cipher = tmp;

    return cipher.VerifyData(
        payment,
        signature,
        HashAlgorithmName.SHA256,
        RSASignaturePadding.Pss);
 }
```

Comment: What is Crypto.DecodeX509PublicKey ? Where does that come from? I can't seem to get that to be referenced correctly in my code.

Comment: @Ristogod it’s a function that was called in the question’s original code. From the perspective of this answer it’s a black box.